# Is there a way to convert an array of arrays to JSON?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, object, ecmascript-6

```
let letter = ["a", "b", "c"];
let number = [1, 2, 3];

let arrays = [letter, number]

// What code will achieve the following result?

let result = [
  {
    letter: "a",
    number: 1,
  },
  {
    letter: "b",
    number: 2,
  },
];
```

Comment: [`JSON.stringify()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify)

Comment: @MichaelM. — While that will convert an array of arrays to JSON … the specific result the OP is asking for isn't JSON.

Comment: There is no JSON in your question. The JSON tag description: _Do not use this tag for native JavaScript objects or JavaScript object literals._

Answer (score 3):

I don't see any array of arrays here but:

```js
let letter = ["a", "b", "c"];
let number = [1, 2, 3];

const array = []
for (let i = 0; i < letter.length; i += 1) {
  array.push({
    number: number[i],
    letter: letter[i]
  })
}

console.log(array)
console.log(JSON.stringify(array))
```

Comment: `let arrays = [letter, number]` is the array of arrays.

Comment: @jabaa this code has been added after I added my answer

Comment: No, the code was added 27 minutes ago. Your answer was added 25 minutes ago. You answered two minutes after the line was added. You can see it in the timeline.

Comment: I was writing my answer when this change happen lol

Comment: Yes, and the question was edited while you were writing the answer. Why wouldn't edited your answer, too? There should be a notification at the top while you were writing and after you submitted your answer. Just to make it clear: it's not my downvote. I only read your answer and it didn't make sense, because the code line was in the question when I edited the question.